# Why is nothing printing and just terminating?

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Foothill {

  static Scanner input;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    input = new Scanner (System.in);

    String[] getNames = new String[5];

    for(int x = 0; x > 5; x++){

        System.out.println("Enter 5 names: ");
        getNames[x] = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print(getNames[x]);          
    }

  }    
}
```

It just terminates. Is there a reason it isn't asking for 5 names and then printing the elements of the array?

Comment: Check your `for` loop condition.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
for(int x = 0; x > 5; x++){
               ^^^^^
                 |
                  -> this will never be true
```

to

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
```

---

**Suggestion:** This kind of errors can be easily found if you trace your code properly (e.g. add some breakpoints).

Answer (score 2):

Your for loop syntax is incorrect,

```
for(int x = 0; x > 5; x++){ // 0 is less then 5.
```

I think you wanted,

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){ // while x is less then 5 (for five elements)
```

Answer (score 2):

It needs to be

```
for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
```

X is never more than five.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for(int x = 0; x < 5; x++){

        System.out.println("Enter 5 names: ");
        getNames[x] = input.nextLine();

        System.out.print(getNames[x]);          
    }
```

I changed the sign in the for loop from : x > 5, to x < 5 since I'm sure you want the for loop to go through while x < 5.